# Add image to layout in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, layout

I would like to add an image in my template for my ruby on rails project where i currenly have the code `<img src="../../../public/images/rss.jpg" alt="rss feed" />` in a the layout `stores.html.erb` file however this doesn't seem to load as it looks like its missing a route which i'm not sure what its supposed to be.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Anything in the `public` folder is accessible at the root path (`/`) so change your img tag to read:

```
<img src="/images/rss.jpg" alt="rss feed" />
```

If you wanted to use a rails tag, use this:

```
<%= image_tag("rss.jpg", :alt => "rss feed") %>
```

Comment: :o thanks a lot, i hadnt come across the image_tag silly me! , set yours as the accepted answer being first ;)

Comment: the img tag has thrown an error for me, while the tag worked fine! :)

Answer (score 14):

In a Ruby on Rails project by default the root of the HTML source for the server is the public directory.  So your link would be:

```
<img src="images/rss.jpg" alt="rss feed" />
```

But it is best practice in a Rails project to use the built in helper:

```
<%= image_tag("rss.jpg", :alt => "rss feed") %>
```

That will create the correct image link plus if you ever add assert servers, etc it will work with those.

Comment: Bahaha. Our answers look identical. Great minds think alike (And I posted first :)

Comment: By a few minutes at best.  I just needed to type faster.

Comment: Haha. Yup! I knew you didn't copy it, that's why it was so funny ;)

Answer (score 6):

When using the new ruby, the image folder will go to asset folder on folder app

after placing your images in image folder, use

```
<%=image_tag("example_image.png", alt: "Example Image")%>
```

Answer (score 3):

simple just use the img tag helper. Rails knows to look in the images folder in the asset pipeline, you can use it like this

```
<%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me:

`<%= image_tag( root_url + "images/rss.jpg", size: "50x50", :alt => "rss feed") -%>`

Answer (score -2):

image_tag is the best way to do the job friend

Comment: Perhaps some more information would improve this answer both for the OP  and other people who need this solution