# picture won't render on page HTML relative path- using foundation and rails

Tags: html, image

[image]this is pretty basic but I can't figure out why my image won't render. The broken image icon doesn't appear and I'm viewing my page on localhost. I'm not sure how to upload a screen shot but I've played with the relative path in many ways and can't figure out the problem. When I link to an online image it renders. I'm using rails/foundation currently but I actually had the same problem using a MEAN stack a couple weeks ago. The issue seems to be only when using a server. Any help is appreciated, thanks. EDIT: my views and assets folder are at the same level (siblings?) views path: app/views/projects/home.html.erb. images path: app/assets/images/volvo.jpg; I've selected the image file and done 'copy relative path' and played with it every which way. I don't think it's the path but who knows.

```
<h4>pic below</h4>
<img src"../../assets/images/bmw.jpg"/>
<h4>pic above</h4>
<h2>photo gallery</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src"assets/images/bmw.jpg"/>
      <img src"../../assets/images/volvo.jpg"/>
      <img src"saab.jpg"/>
      <img src"../../assets/images/saabtwo.jpg"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: This looks like it should work, and the tools to add a picture are built into the editor.

Comment: what do you mean the tools to add the picture?

Comment: When you edit your post there is a button that looks like a small landscape drawing that is used to add images.

Comment: I noticed you had some things wrong in your code, sorry I didn't notice sooner. I posted an answer for you detailing this.

Comment: You are editing a template, not a page. The actual path of the rendered file will not be the same as the template.  Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814736/add-image-to-layout-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Perfect! thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining your [images](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) incorrectly; you forgot the equals sign (=). You need to have `src=` instead of just `src` before the image path. This is because of the way the defining/setting of [attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) works in html.

For your code, this would be:

```
<h4>pic below</h4>
<img src="../../assets/images/bmw.jpg"/>
<h4>pic above</h4>
<h2>photo gallery</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="assets/images/bmw.jpg"/>
      <img src="../../assets/images/volvo.jpg"/>
      <img src="saab.jpg"/>
      <img src="../../assets/images/saabtwo.jpg"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

As a general rule, to define a style in html, you do this: `attribute="value"`.

Comment: Sorry, I took a screen shot at the wrong time, I had also done 'src=' and am not getting to render, just the broken image link. Also, can you elaborate on where I should be including attribute="value"? Thanks

Comment: @KM617 See this for the attributes: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp. Could you update your screenshot if that is the case, please?

Comment: sorry for the slow response, I've updated with a current screen shot