# Tried it all, still can't get local images to show in HTML pages

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've tried all sorts of different addressing methods, but I can't get the HTML right to show images which are locally held in the site's directory.  The app is set up on GitHub and Heroku, using ruby on rails, if that makes any difference.  You can see the code below, where I'm trying to get a favicon and logo to show up on all my pages with the application.html.erb file.

Can anybody see something wrong with those lines of code?  Here's what the directory looks like.

```
app/assets/images/favicon.png and navbar-logo.png sit here
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
app/views/layouts/all the pages, e.g. home.html.erb, sit here
```

Thanks!

Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Harvest Loop</title>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&subset=Latin">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../../assets/images/favicon.png"/>
    </head>

    <body>

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-custom">
      <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="../../assets/images/navbar-logo.png" alt="haifai"></a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Demo", demo_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would guess that you would have to insert those Ruby on Rails "<%=" sequences of characters somewhere in the href. I think it is called "image_tag" or something. I do not use Ruby on Rails, but if I had to guess from my experience with Django, you would have to use the back end templating system in someway instead of just straight up giving hard links like you are there. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814736/add-image-to-layout-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: What Iceman said. You need to use a rails helper method because of issues involving the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the assets helpers, [`favicon_link_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag) in this case

```
favicon_link_tag 'favicon.png'
```

and [`image_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) here

```
image_tag 'navbar-logo.png'
```