# HTML to Ruby on Rails : link and image tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

While integrating a theme into my rails project I encountered a problem with images.  I know, there are several variations of this question asked before and plenty of resources out there, but I have still been having a little trouble figuring out how to change the below code to work in my Rails 5 project.

```
<div class="content">    
    <a href="assets/images/portfolio/one.jpg" rel="gallery"><img src="assets/images/portfolio/one.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

I have tried various solutions but am still getting broken images.
The thing is that there is some styling attached to the `rel="gallery"` attribute that I want to keep.  I'm pretty unsure how this would work exactly.

My image `one.jpg` is located in `vendor/assets/images/one.jpg`.

My first instinct was to do:

```
   <%= link_to image_tag("/vendor/assets/images/s-1.jpg"),
 some_path("/vendor/assets/images/s-1.jpg") %>
```

but I know this is not quite right:  I'm unsure what path to use, and this still does not consider the styling from the relationship attribute.

Comment: i think this will help you [Add image to layout in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814736/add-image-to-layout-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Thanks..I will definitely read through it & appreciate your attention...  I'm still pretty new to RoR and get tripped up on some basic things quite often.  Pretty sure I found a good solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe I've come up with the solution.  The image is loading properly, and is linking to the same image which has retained all of the styling from the `rel="gallery"` attribute.

```
<%= link_to (image_tag("s-1.jpg")), image_path("s-1.jpg"), rel: "gallery" %>
```

I'm curious to know if this is the best way to do this, and if not, what are the alternatives.